# UIButton with no image doesn't highlight in Xcode 7 - iOS 9.2

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, storyboard

I'm making my first app in Swift and I noticed that when I create UIButtons in the storyboard when selected (highlighted) in the app they only change background if the button is an image.

I was wondering if there is any way in Swift to change that so that even the buttons with no image will change their background to a darker background.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: On button click action change the background color of the button.

Comment: You must set type to System

Comment: If I set the type to System I can't get the custom font that I want and besides that only the label changes color while I'm trying to get the background to change as well!

Answer (score 1):

UIButton's default behaviour is to change its background on click.
try dragging a new UIButton on Interface Builder, and run the program without doing any changes to the button.

With your specific button, inspect it in Interface Builder and check that its type is System, otherwise you don't get that default behaviour.

[image]

Comment: Doing that the text "Button" changes color but the background stays the same, I'm trying to change it to a darker background just as it does when there is an image in the button! Do you know how could I achieve that?